# c++ binary write or read

Tags: c++, fwrite

I have a problem when I tried to make a conversion of a text to binary format:

As described in the code below, it worked well for test3.txt or test4.txt, however, `fout3.write(str1.data() ,len);` doesn't work for test5.txt (WHICH REALLY puzzled me) so I used `fout3.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(& str1) ,len);` instead, and it worked well.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   ofstream fout("test3.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
   fout << "ABC\n";
   fout.close();

   int test =  111;
   ofstream fout1("test4.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
   fout1.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&test), sizeof(int));
   fout1.close();

   int test2;
   ifstream fin("test4.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
   fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&test2), sizeof(int));
   cout << test2 << endl;

   string str1 = "ATEGWGEf";
   int len = str1.length();
   cout << str1.data() << endl;
   ofstream fout3("test6.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
// fout3.write(str1.data() ,len);
   fout3.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(& str1) ,len);
   fout3.close();

   string line;
   ifstream fin2("test6.txt",  ios::in | ios::binary);
   fin2.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&line),300);
   cout << line << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

But another question come to me. When I tried to read test6.txt, which was just wrote,
 it failed with error like this.

```
*** glibc detected *** ./binary_file.debug: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001e4c260 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3155275366]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x39)[0x317209d4c9]
./binary_file.debug[0x4010f3]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x315521ecdd]
./binary_file.debug[0x400d69]
======= Memory map: ========
......................
01e4a000-01e6b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3154a00000-3154a20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3031286                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3154c1f000-3154c20000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 3031286                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3154c20000-3154c21000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 3031286                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3154c21000-3154c22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3155200000-3155389000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3033037                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3155389000-3155588000 ---p 00189000 fd:00 3033037                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3155588000-315558c000 r--p 00188000 fd:00 3033037                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
315558c000-315558d000 rw-p 0018c000 fd:00 3033037                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
315558d000-3155592000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3155600000-3155683000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3033062                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3155683000-3155882000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 3033062                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3155882000-3155883000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 3033062                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3155883000-3155884000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 3033062                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3171c00000-3171c16000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 3014674                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3171c16000-3171e15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 3014674                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3171e15000-3171e16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 3014674                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3172000000-31720e8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1719247                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
31720e8000-31722e8000 ---p 000e8000 fd:00 1719247                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
31722e8000-31722ef000 r--p 000e8000 fd:00 1719247                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
31722ef000-31722f1000 rw-p 000ef000 fd:00 1719247                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
31722f1000-3172306000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f1142209000-7f114220e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f114222d000-7f1142230000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff7ff9c000-7fff7ffb1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff7ffff000-7fff80000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Together with this error, I successfully convert binary test6.txt to texts by accident. I really want to know why and how to fix this bug.

Thx!

Comment: Please make the title of your question more descriptive of the actual problem you are having.

Comment: You should try using `fout3.write(str1.c_str(), str1.size());`

Comment: I don't understand how you can just "reinterpret_cast" a class like std::string.  std::string isn't just an array of characters!  There are actual fields in there.

Comment: I don't understand why it didn't work when you used `str1.data()`? What was the error? See http://ideone.com/YB4pPI

Comment: The question is that what I want is binary output rather than characters.

Comment: `fout3.write(str1.c_str(), str1.size());` would not make a binary output in test6.txt, the result is ATEGWGEf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem with reading is in this line:

```
fin2.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&line),300);
```

What are you doing is casting the address of `string` object into a `char *` pointer. Then you are overwriting its internal content. This is wrong and it will never work. Some people suggest using this:

```
fin2.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&line.c_str()),300);
```

Well it can compile, but it should crash at runtime. The reason is that `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char *` and you are casting away the `const` with `reinterpret_cast`. Also
this is `UB` because the C++98 standard says:

> A program shall not alter any of the characters in this sequence.

Comment: That's right. `fin2.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(line.c_str()),300);` would come to a type error and `fin2.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(line.c_str()),300);` result in `reinterpret_cast from type 'const char*' to type 'char*' casts away constness`. But is there any way to store a string in binary format?

Comment: @user3191525 Well, you just declare a char array and store the string there: `char line[300]; fin2.read(line, 300);`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just convert a pointer to a class to a char* and write the data to a file.
How do you expects pointers to be interpreted, for example? They won't point to valid addresses any more when read, and you don't take then into consideration when writing, you just write the addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::string::c_str()` to acquire a pointer to the internal buffer of the string.